# How to iterate over a 3 dimensional tensor

Tags: numpy, iteration, tensor

I have a tensor say:

```
y_true = np.array([[[1.], [0.], [3.]], [[5.], [0.], [0.]]])
```

I want to iterate over y_true accessing all indevidual values. I want to do something like following in java:

```
for(i=0;i<y_true.length;i++){
    arr2 = y_true[i];
    for(j=0;j<arr2.length;j++){
        print(arr2[j][0])
    }
}.
```

Comment: Have you tried writing the incredibly similar python equivalent of that java code?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for slicing with `[:,:,0]`?

```
>>> y_true[:,:,0]
array([[1., 0., 3.],
       [5., 0., 0.]])
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 cases:

1. You know the rank(dimensionality) of your created numpy array in the example `y_true` array has rank of 3, and you can check `y_true.shape` property which should give you with exact size of each dimension of the `y_true`, then you can write as many for loops the rank of `y_true` and output each element separately, for example:

   ```
   import numpy as np

   y_true = np.array([[[1.], [0.], [3.]], [[5.], [0.], [0.]]])
   dims = y_true.shape
   for i in range(dims[0]):
       for j in range(dims[1]):
           for k in range(dims[2]):
               print("Element of np array with indices {} is equal to {}".format([i, j, k], y_true[i, j, k]))
   ```
2. If you don't know the rank of the tensor you want to print then you can write recursive function that will print all the elements, for example:

   ```
   import numpy as np    


   def recursively_print_elems(np_arr, idx, pos):
       if pos >= len(np_arr.shape):
           print("Element of np array with indeces {} is equal to: {}".format(idx, np_arr[tuple(idx)]))
           return
       for i in range(np_arr.shape[pos]):
           idx[pos] = i
           recursively_print_elems(np_arr, idx, pos + 1)


   def print_elems(np_arr):
       idx = [0] * len(np_arr.shape)
       recursively_print_elems(np_arr, idx, 0)


   y_true = np.array([[[1.], [0.], [3.]], [[5.], [0.], [0.]]])
   print_elems(y_true)
   ```

The 2nd approach is more general it will work for any dimensional tensor.

---

Answer (score 0):

Your array:

```
In [19]: y_true
Out[19]: 
array([[[1.],
        [0.],
        [3.]],

       [[5.],
        [0.],
        [0.]]])
In [20]: y_true.shape
Out[20]: (2, 3, 1)
```

With a last dimension of size 1, we can reshape it

```
In [21]: y_true.reshape(2,3)
Out[21]: 
array([[1., 0., 3.],
       [5., 0., 0.]])
```

Selecting on that index does just as well.

But you can access all values in order just by raveling/flattening:

```
In [22]: y_true.ravel()
Out[22]: array([1., 0., 3., 5., 0., 0.])
```

Or get a 1 iterator:

```
In [23]: yiter = y_true.flat
In [24]: yiter?
Type:            flatiter
String form:     <numpy.flatiter object at 0x1fdd200>
Length:          6
File:            ~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py
Docstring:       <no docstring>
Class docstring:
Flat iterator object to iterate over arrays.

A `flatiter` iterator is returned by ``x.flat`` for any array `x`.
It allows iterating over the array as if it were a 1-D array,
either in a for-loop or by calling its `next` method.
...
```

So instead of constructing an iterator for each dimension we can iterate on this flat one:

```
In [25]: for item in yiter:print(item)
1.0
0.0
3.0
5.0
0.0
0.0
```

`ndenumerate` uses this flat iterator, and returns both coordinates and values:

```
In [26]: list(np.ndenumerate(y_true))
Out[26]: 
[((0, 0, 0), 1.0),
 ((0, 1, 0), 0.0),
 ((0, 2, 0), 3.0),
 ((1, 0, 0), 5.0),
 ((1, 1, 0), 0.0),
 ((1, 2, 0), 0.0)]
```

A variation on this is `ndindex`:

```
In [27]: indexs = np.ndindex(y_true.shape)
In [28]: for ijk in indexs:
    ...:     print(ijk, y_true[ijk])
    ...:     
(0, 0, 0) 1.0
(0, 1, 0) 0.0
(0, 2, 0) 3.0
(1, 0, 0) 5.0
(1, 1, 0) 0.0
(1, 2, 0) 0.0
```

But where possible it is better to operate on the whole array, rather than iterate.  Those whole-array operations do the iteration in compiled code.